# How to access one directive scope value to other directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Actually my requirement is to get the one directive scope to another directive and need to perform the two way binding.

I need to change that JSON values whenever the ng-model will get change. In the below example JSON having rowset with attributes. These attribute names i have to bind the with control(textbox) like ng-model=CuId. So whenever the corresponding attributes value will get change the JSON need to be update.

Source Code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive("main", function() {

});

app.directive("sub1", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template : "<h1>sub1</h1>",
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
           $scope.soJSON={
                "entityinfo": {
                  "entity": "Customer29Jan16",
                  "tenantId": "292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098",
                  "timeStamp": "2016-04-07T10:33:38.507Z"
                },
                "collections": {
                  "Customer29Jan16": {
                    "meta": {
                      "parentreference": "***",
                      "pkname": "***",
                      "fkname": "***"
                    },
                    "rowset": [
                      {
                        "CuId": "test",
                        "Name": "test",
                        "Quantity": "test"                       
                      }
                    ],
                    "rowfilter": []
                  }
                }
              }
        }
    };
});

app.directive("sub2", function() {
    return {
        template : "<input ng-model=CuId> <input ng-model=Name> <input ng-model=Quantity>"
    };
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<main>
   <sub1>Test<</sub1>
   <sub2>Test<</sub2>
</main>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/bagya1985/23vz1xux/1/

Answer (score 1):

Well AngularJS supports directive controllers, which are controllers that are shared between multiple directives that require the same controller.you would need to use `require:'^main'` in your child directives . for more information you can check out the link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: can you please guide using my fiddle link.